# How to do a join query on a dataset that has multiple tables using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I'm reading two XML files into one dataset. I do this by reading my first xml file into a dataset, read my second xml file into another dataset and I then merge the two datasets into one dataset. I'm not sure if this is the best and most efficient way to do this.

```
xmlFilePath = "C:\RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUGS.xml"
dsInfusions_min.ReadXml(xmlFilePath)

xmlFilePath = "C:\RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CAT.xml"
dsWeight.ReadXml(xmlFilePath)

dsMain.Merge(dsInfusions_min.Tables(0))
dsMain.Merge(dsWeight.Tables(0))
```

So now my dsMain dataset has two tables. My question is, how can I perform a select statement that would join the two tables such as the select below, and have the result merged into another dataset?

```
SELECT
    D.DRUG_NAME,
    D.DRUG_UNITS,
    D.PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY
FROM
    RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUGS D, RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CAT C
WHERE
    D.PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY = C.PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY AND
    15 <  C.MAXIMUM_WEIGHT and
    15 >= C.MINIMUM_WEIGHT
ORDER BY
    D.DRUG_NAME
```

Here are my two xml files...

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORIES>
    <RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
        <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>00</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
        <MINIMUM_WEIGHT>0</MINIMUM_WEIGHT>
        <MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>9999</MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>
        <CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>All patients, regardless of weight.   </CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>
    <UPDATED_WHEN>2003-08-20 12:00:57</UPDATED_WHEN>
</RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
<RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>01</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <MINIMUM_WEIGHT>0</MINIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>4</MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>Patients less than 4 Kg.</CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>
    <UPDATED_WHEN>2003-08-20 12:01:23</UPDATED_WHEN>
</RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
<RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>02</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <MINIMUM_WEIGHT>4</MINIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>9999</MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>Patients greater than 4 Kg.</CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>
    <UPDATED_WHEN>2003-08-20 12:01:52</UPDATED_WHEN>
</RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
<RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>03</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <MINIMUM_WEIGHT>0</MINIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>5</MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>Patients less than 5 Kg.</CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>
    <UPDATED_WHEN>2007-10-18 13:46:43</UPDATED_WHEN>
</RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
<RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>04</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <MINIMUM_WEIGHT>5</MINIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>9999</MAXIMUM_WEIGHT>
    <CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>Patients greater than 5 Kg.</CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION>
    <UPDATED_WHEN>2007-10-18 13:47:23</UPDATED_WHEN>
</RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
```

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUGS>
<RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUG>
    <DRUG_NAME>DOBUTamine</DRUG_NAME>
    <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>07</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <DRUG_CONCENTRATION>12.5</DRUG_CONCENTRATION>
    <DRUG_CONCENTRATION_UNITS>mg/mL</DRUG_CONCENTRATION_UNITS>
    <DOSAGE_RATE>1</DOSAGE_RATE>
    <DOSAGE_RATE_UNITS>mL/h</DOSAGE_RATE_UNITS>
    <DOSAGE_RATIO>2</DOSAGE_RATIO>
    <DOSAGE_RATIO_UNITS>mcg/kg/min</DOSAGE_RATIO_UNITS>
    <SOLUTION_PREPARATION></SOLUTION_PREPARATION>
    <SOLUTION_UNITS>mg in 50 mL D5W</SOLUTION_UNITS>
    <VOLUME_UNITS>mL</VOLUME_UNITS>
    <SOLUTION_CONCENTRATION></SOLUTION_CONCENTRATION>
    <DRUG_VOLUME></DRUG_VOLUME>
</RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUG>
<RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUG>
    <DRUG_NAME>DOPamine</DRUG_NAME>
    <PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>03</PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY>
    <DRUG_CONCENTRATION>3.2</DRUG_CONCENTRATION>
    <DRUG_CONCENTRATION_UNITS>mg/mL</DRUG_CONCENTRATION_UNITS>
    <DOSAGE_RATE></DOSAGE_RATE>
    <DOSAGE_RATE_UNITS>mL/h</DOSAGE_RATE_UNITS>
    <DOSAGE_RATIO>5</DOSAGE_RATIO>
    <DOSAGE_RATIO_UNITS>mcg/kg/min</DOSAGE_RATIO_UNITS>
    <SOLUTION_PREPARATION>160</SOLUTION_PREPARATION>
    <SOLUTION_UNITS>mg in 50 mL D5W</SOLUTION_UNITS>
    <VOLUME_UNITS>mL</VOLUME_UNITS>
    <SOLUTION_CONCENTRATION>3200</SOLUTION_CONCENTRATION>
    <DRUG_VOLUME></DRUG_VOLUME>
</RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUG>
```

I want to join the two xml files on the PATIENT_WEIGHT_CATEGORY field.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at LINQ to DataSet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx

Comment: Not sure if this is possible for you but why dont import the XML files into a SQL table and then use the table(s) to get to the results you need?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use datasets if you have straight XML data. This is one area that VB.NET is better than C# IMHO.

```
  Dim Table1 = XDocument.Load("path to file")...<rootElement>...<rowElement>

  Dim Table2 = XDocument.Load("path to file")...<rootElement>...<rowElement>


  Dim result = Table1.Join(inner:=Table2,

                        outerKeySelector:=Function(o) o.Key,

                        innerKeySelector:=Function(i) i.Key,

                        resultSelector:=Function(i,o) With New {.fieldName:= o.@f1,

                                                                .fieldName2:= i.@f2})
```

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

The other thing you could also do is convert the xml to expando objects and still do the join operation.

i.e.
      Dim Table1 = XDocument.Load("paty to the file")......        .Select(Function(r as XElement)
                         Dim record as Object = New Dynamic.ExpandoObject()
                         record.FieldName = r.@Field.Value())

If you provide the actual schema I could provide a better example.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for all the replies everyone.

Comment: I posted a sample of my two xml files.

Comment: I coded it up for you the code is at https://gist.github.com/jcwrequests/6616176.  Basically I embeded your two files as resources. Source1 is RESUSCITATION_WEIGHT_CATEGORIES and Source2 is RESUSCITATION_INFUSION_DRUGS.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample but it must be the fact that I'm Java guy, but I can't make heads or tails of that code. I assume that your sample is using linq? I didn't think of mentioning this earlier, but the reason why I'd like to use datasets (or at least have the final results feed back to a dataset) is because I'm modifying an existing application and if I stick with datasets I won't have to change a lot of the existing code.

Comment: Our application currently connects to an Oracle database to get the data, that data is static and there is very little of it, so the idea was to store that data in xml files to remove the need for an Oracle database. So if I could simply change the source from Oracle to xml files by sticking with a dataset I won't need to change any other section of my application. It does work, but if all my data were in one xml file, but unfortunately I need to join several xml files. I'm wondering if it will be a whole lot more simple to simply use an Access database instead of xml files?

Comment: That code can easily be turned into a dataset. It's to bad I did not have those details earlier but tha being said this will still work but I think you are better off using something like SQLite and say Simple.Data on top of that if you need something simple. SQLite has bulk insert capabities with CSV files so if your data is basically static its easy to insert the data in the db then distrubute it. Not to mention its open source. Good Luck.

Comment: By the way I just updated the gits it now shows how to covert your query into a dataset.